# .NET Regex: Get all matched groups

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I've stuck with regex problem using .NET. For example, I have next regex pattern: **(?'group1'A|C)|(?'group2'B|C)|(?'group3'A|B|C)**

When I do match of "*AXYZ*" I receive match object which contains Value and Groups; if I go to Groups I'll see that only one group has success in true - **group1** (group3 is in false). If I do match of "*BXYZ*" I'll receive only **group2** with success in true (group3 is in false).

How could I receive in match not only one group but all groups satisfying the match?

For example above it should be: group1 & group3 in "*AXYZ*" and group2 & group3 in "*BXYZ*".

*All above is only example in real system there are different patterns (3+ letters each) and more complicated input text (1000+ words).*

Comment: Do you mean group1 & group2 & group3 for "BXYZ"?  bc they all match B right?

Comment: I mean that for "BXYZ" should match group2 and group3, but in fact I receive only group2 (FYI if change order 2<->3 in regex pattern then I'll receive group3, it seems that it just takes first group).

Comment: You could make them separate regular expressions and apply them one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

The question seems a little abstract, but if you insist on a single regex you can do something like this, using optional [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?=(?'group1'A|C)?)(?=(?'group2'B|C)?)(?=(?'group3'A|B|C)?)
```

Lookaheads match but don't capture, so your match will be empty in this case, but the groups will be as you expect, and may overlap.

Working example: **http://ideone.com/PTtQu**

Comment: Oh, and I'm missing an anchor here. A string like `acb` will have multiple matches, you may want `\b` or `^` before the pattern.

Comment: Hm... but it doesn't work with strings like `XYZ ABC` and etc.

Comment: @Jo - Well, you never mentioned *how it supposed to work* `:)`. Please edit your question extensively and explain what you expect. If I understand correctly, you may use `((?=(?'group1'A|C)?)(?=(?'group2'B|C)?)(?=(?'group3'A|B|C)?).)+`, and look for the `Captures` of each group.

Comment: In real system all of patterns are different from example above of course. It could be like: `(?=(?'group1'product|system)?)(?=(?'group2'functions|product)?)(?=(?'group3'stars|product|desktop)?)` and input text could be more complicated like text with about 1000+ words.

Answer (score 1):

The regex you have there will only match single characters; as soon as a match has been found on a character, the regex moves onto the next character in the input string. In your example, 'B' will never be matched by 'group2' or 'group3' as it will always be matched by 'group1'. Similarly, 'A' will never be matched by 'group3' for the same reason.

One way of getting the outcome you require using regexes is to treat each group as a separate regex and use `Regex.IsMatch()` on each one. For counts, the following C# does what I think you're asking for:

```
string input = "AXYZ";
int count = 0;

count += Regex.IsMatch(input, "A|B") ? 1 : 0;
count += Regex.IsMatch(input, "B|C") ? 1 : 0;
count += Regex.IsMatch(input, "A|B|D") ? 1 : 0;

Console.WriteLine(count); // returns 2
```

Comment: I thought about it but in this case I have other problems with count of matches and etc. It would be better to do it in one Regex... do you know how I could do this with one Regex but with multiple patterns?

Comment: Thanks for example but I have more complicated task. I have some groups with patterns like I wrote in entry post:
`group1: A|C    group2: B|C    group3: A|B|D`

and I need to get number of matches of every expression in every group, something like next:
`A: 5 matches: group1 & group3   B: 3 matches: group2 & group3   C: 1 matches: group3`

I thought that I can do it in one query but it seems that I need to do something else, like loop and etc.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to make the regex "greedy". Here is some info on it:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2005/08/19/453869.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The regex engine is eager, which means it will always return the left-most match and stop matching once a match is found. To demonstrate, consider this sample:

```
string input = "Hello World";
string pattern = "Hello|Hello World";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(input, pattern).Value);
pattern = "Hello World|Hello";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(input, pattern).Value);
```

In your case group1 is matched first, so all other groups will not match and return `false`. Also, you claim that "BXYZ" returns group2, but this can't be right. Both "AXYZ" and "BXYZ" get matched by group1: `(?'group1'A|B)`. If you have a need to test each group you'll need to do so using a separate regex.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I did a mistake: (?'group1'A|C)|(?'group2'B|C)|(?'group3'A|B|C)... but anyway I understood the problem and it's pity that I cannot do it with one Regex =(

Comment: @Jo - Please edit the question and correct that error - it is very confusing.